# Django-Rest-Framework-Filters: Using custom queryset methods in a filter being consumed via a RelatedFilter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm using [Django-Rest-Framework-Filters](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters) in a similar manner as [documented here](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters#supporting-filtermethod). I would like to filter Author by some condition on the related Post class which is using a custom `PostQuerySet` queryset method. The filter, `myfilter`, is defined on `PostFilter` filterset as:

```
class PostFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    myfilter = filters.BooleanFilter(name='date_published', method='filter_myfilter')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']

    def filter_myfilter(self, qs, name, value):
        """
        Calls myqueryset_method defined on PostQuerySet 
        """
        return qs.myqueryset_method()

class AuthorFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    posts = filters.RelatedFilter('PostFilter', queryset=Post.objects.all())

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['name']
```

The trouble is, when trying to use this filter as part of Author's API, e.g.

```
/api/authors?posts__myfilter=true
```

an error is thrown:

> "AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'myqueryset_method'"

It seems counter-intuitive, but it appears you cannot execute the PostQuerySet method on the `qs` arugment because it is not a Post queryset when called by the RelatedFilter. As explained in the docs:

```
[when making the filter calls]

/api/posts?is_published=true
/api/authors?posts__is_published=true

"In the first API call, the filter method receives a queryset of posts. In the second, it receives a queryset of users."
```

So how can you leverage **custom queryset methods** in the filter that is being consumed through a RelatedFilter?

Comment: The short answer is that this isn't feasible at the moment and is dependent on a solution to [#99](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters/issues/99). I've been slowly plugging away at this issue for a while, but have ran into performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to work around this issue, achieving the semantics of a 'chained nested join' (q3) described in the  [discussion](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters/issues/99) that [sherpa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1103124/sherpa) linked.

The code below is a bit rough but its basically just chains the filter to qs when the model types are the same (`qs.model == filterset._meta.model`).

If they are different, then effectively do a nested join on the (Author) qs.

In utils.py:

```
from django.db.models.constants import LOOKUP_SEP

def get_lookup_expression(name):

    # The name argument contains the filter to apply. NOTE - if this filter is consumed via a RelatedFilter,
    # i.e. on AuthorFilter, the filters list will contain ['author', 'filter_myfilter']
    filters = name.split(LOOKUP_SEP)

    # Remove the final filter name from filter list -this should handle filtering over multiple traversed models 
    filter = LOOKUP_SEP.join(filters[:-1])

    # Create new lookup expression, i.e. 'author__in'
    lookup_expr = LOOKUP_SEP.join([filter, 'in'])

    return lookup_expr


def related_filter_handler(func, filterset, qs, name, value):

    # Get model in the queryset and the model defined in the filterset
    qs_model = qs.model
    filter_model = filterset._meta.model

    if (qs_model == filter_model):
        # If they are equal then we are applying the filter directly on the model via its API, e.g. '/api/posts?customfilter=true'
        return func(qs, value)
    else:
        # They will be different when calling '/api/author?post__customfilter=true'

        # Apply filter to filter_model
        T2 = func(filter_model.objects.all(), value)

        # Construct lookup_expr 'X__in' where X is the path to traverse from the related (qs) model
        lookup_expr = get_lookup_expression(name)

        # Filters RelatedFilter qs, i.e. qs.filter(post__in=T2)
        return qs.filter(**{lookup_expr: T2})
```

In filters.py:

```
import rest_framework_filters as filters
from .utils import related_filter_handler
from .models import Post

class PostFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    myfilter = filters.BooleanFilter(name='date_published', method='customfilter')

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'content']

    def customfilter(self, qs, name, value):
        """
        Calls myqueryset_method defined on PostQuerySet 
        """
        # Wrap the filter logic in function/lambda
        def apply(qs, value):
            # e.g. passing in value to the queryset method
            return qs.myqueryset_method(value) 

        # Pass filter expression into helper function which handles chaining the filter as is or chaining a nested join 
        return related_filter_handler(apply, self, qs, name, value)
```

The work around passes my unit tests. But it might run into trouble if you're dealing with proxy models. Feel free to edit to make improvements to the code.

It would be a lot better if this was the native behaviour of the RelatedFilter as you'd have to code all of your custom filter methods against future/unknown use via RelatedFilters.